# How do I resolve OSX rpath-referenced library?

Tags: macos, ld

I want to link a DLL using a couple of other DLLs but am having trouble getting them to properly resolve:

```
$ g++ -o libsuba.dylib -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,@rpath/libsuba.dylib suba.cpp

$ g++ -o liba.dylib -dynamiclib -Wl,-install_name,@rpath/liba.dylib -Wl,-reexport_library,libsuba.dylib a.cpp
```

The above gives me the two libraries, liba.dylib and libsuba.dylib.

```
$ otool -l liba.dylib

...
Load command 10
          cmd LC_REEXPORT_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name @rpath/libsuba.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 18:00:02 1969
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
...
```

In another directory, I want to now link against liba.dylib:

```
$ cd build
$ c++ -o b b.cpp ../liba.dylib -Wl,-rpath,..
ld: file not found: @rpath/libsuba.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, this works:

```
$ c++ -o b b.cpp ../liba.dylib -L..
```

Can someone explain why the explicit linker rpath option doesn't replace the @rpath macro and allow the reexported library to be located?

Comment: I'm not too sure about what I'm going to say, but I thought that rpath is used by the dynamic linker at runtime, not by the static linker at compile-time.

Comment: I think you're right.  Thanks.  But then I wonder what happens to the @rpath macro in the library name.  It's probably just ignored, which in this case would be the same as replacing it with search paths.